# MySQL Connector/python not working in django

Tags: python, mysql, django, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I'm learning Django with MySQL as backend. I installed Oracle's mysql connector to connect with mysql. However, when I run `python manage.py` I got this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 14, in 
>       import MySQLdb as Database
>   ImportError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

That's a bit weird. I was thinking if I installed mysql connector/python I dont need MySQLdb anymore.

Could anyone help explain? Thanks!

My database setting:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': "djangolearn",
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    'PORT': '3306',
}}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
# for mysql connector use this

DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
    'NAME': 'dbname',               
    'USER': 'user',
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    'PORT': '3306',
},
```

}

Comment: mysql-connector-python, starting from version 8.0.13, has a bug, which makes it impossible to use with Django:

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30469  
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=92001  

To avoid the bug, add option `'use_pure': True` in the database options.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Oracle's connector, you need to use their Django db backend.

See [their documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-django-backend.html).

Comment: Thanks! I also just saw it.

Answer (score 1):

Try: pip install mysql-python

If that does not work: make sure you can connect to your database (use phpmyadmin or mysql workbench to test that)

Answer (score 1):

> try this for **MySQL Connector** that working in django:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'djangolearn',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

> or try this for **MySQL Connector pool** that working in django:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'PyMysqlPool.mysql.connector.django',
        'NAME': 'djangolearn',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'autocommit': True,
            'pool': {
                #use = 0 no pool else use pool
                "use":0,
                # size is >=0,  0 is dynamic pool
                "size":10,
                #pool name
                "name":"local",
            }
        },
    }
}
```